# Does the "MUI Data Grid X Pro component" support the use of a footer row

Tags: material-ui

I'm currently evaluating the features of the "MUI Data Grid X Pro component" and am not sure if this component allows to have a (possibly pinned) footer row that can be used to (for example) shows the totals over all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Row pinning](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-pinning/) is the way to go for this